# Why isn't my menu transition being applied?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to create a navbar but the animation are not working, As you can see, I have put  `position: fixed;` and  `right: -100%;` to the  `.nav-links` so that it can hide and not create white space at the right and `#nav-btn:checked~.nav-links { right: 0; width: 100% !important; }`
And when I click at the checkbox it does not show the animation and appear without any animation and that's my problem.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  background: black;
  width: 100% !important;
  color: white;
  height: 76px;
  line-height: 76px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20pt !important;
}

.nav-links a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav-btn,
label {
  display: none;
}

@media(min-width: 600px) {
  label {}
  .nav-links a {
    color: white;
  }
  .nav-links {
    float: right;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .nav-links a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 2.5px;
    padding-bottom: 2.5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-right: 2.5px;
    padding-left: 2.5px;
  }
  .title,
  .nav-links {
    display: inline;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 599px) {
  .nav-links {
    background-color: black;
  }
  label {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
  .extra {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-links {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-links a {
    display: block;
    transition: .9s;
  }
  nav {
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
  .nav-links a:hover,
  .active {
    background: #ff000a;
    color: white;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: fixed;
    right: -100%;
  }
  #nav-btn:checked~.nav-links {
    right: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e8f9edfb9f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    &#10240;<span class="title">Nav</span>
    <label for="nav-btn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="nav-btn">
    <div class="nav-links">
      <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="css.html">About</a>
      <a href="css.html">Contact Us</a>
      <a href="css.html">Feedback</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: In your css i don't see any animation for the div nav-links

Comment: It sounds like you mean _transition_, not animation. There's a difference in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to put the transition on the nav links *container*, not the links. That's where the open/close happens.

I've also moved your width rule to the container for all states, not just when it's shown. That fixes the close transition.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  background: black;
  width: 100% !important;
  color: white;
  height: 76px;
  line-height: 76px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20pt !important;
}

.nav-links a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav-btn,
label {
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 9599px) {
  .nav-links {
    background-color: black;
    transition: .9s;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  label {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
  .extra {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-links a {
    display: block;
  }
  nav {
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
  .nav-links a:hover,
  .active {
    background: #ff000a;
    color: white;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: fixed;
    right: -100%;
  }
  #nav-btn:checked~.nav-links {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e8f9edfb9f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    &#10240;<span class="title">Nav</span>
    <label for="nav-btn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="nav-btn">

    <div class="nav-links">
      <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="css.html">About</a>
      <a href="css.html">Contact Us</a>
      <a href="css.html">Feedback</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```